# JQXdropdown issue in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jqxdropdownlist.js for dropdown in PHP. While onchanging I need to redirect respective pages.

The probem is for example in my dropdown i have the following values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var source = [
                    "Affogato",
                    "Americano",
                    "Bicerin",
                    "Breve",
                    "Café Bombón",
                    "Café au lait",
                    "Caffé Corretto",
                    "Café Crema",
                    "Caffé Latte",
                ];
                // Create a jqxDropDownList
                $("#jqxdropdownlist").jqxDropDownList({ source: source, selectedIndex: 0, width: '200px', height: '25px' });
```

In that I want to choose "**Café au lait**" it should be in 2 in C series. While clicking C letter the drop down comes to 1st series of C that is **Café Bombón** after it will redirect to **Café Bombón** page. But I need to redirect to next series.

I am using the below code for Onchage function.

```
$("#jqxWidget").change(function(){
    var val1=$("#jqxWidget").jqxDropDownList('getItem', args.index);
    window.location.href=val1.value;

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is happening on change.

Comment: That redirect to first drop down itself. I can't able to go to next drop down.

Comment: and where is you next dropdown

Comment: sounds to me like an array index problem where your typical array starts with 0 instead of 1 as in your sql tables

Comment: @jai For example i have 5 dropdown values. I want to choose 4th one. So I am using downarrow to choose 4th one. But if i come to 1st value it self it is redirecting. Can you understand my problem?

Comment: @techouse This was my exact problem.

 For example i have 5 dropdown values. I want to choose 4th one. So I am using downarrow to choose 4th one. But if i come to 1st value it self it is redirecting. Can you understand my problem?

Comment: @Hariprbhu brother can u make a fiddle source for this so that we can see the issue and troubleshoot it, if you can. That will be more than useful.

Comment: Well, if i understand it correctly, the 1st element has the index of 0, so it could potentially break your workflow. Try adding 1 to the indexes, so that the 1st index starts with 1 instead of 0.

Probably something like this:
`var val1=$("#jqxWidget").jqxDropDownList('getItem', parseInt(args.index) + 1);`
Not sure if that will work though, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way and see if this works for you:

```
// i think this will be your hidden input's id change event so
$("#jqxWidget").change(function(){ 
    var val1=$(this).val();
    window.location.href=val1;
});
```